# Toggle a partial show/hide list in a web components with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, web-component

I'm currently learning about web components. With that, I've been working on a toggle to show/hide some elements of a list. I have a `countries.json` file where I have the data of several countries. An HTML file where I'm calling my `show-countries` tag and a `script.js` where I have created my web component. My json has at least 100 countries but I wanna display only 5 and have a button that, when clicked, it will display the rest of the countries from the json, and when clicked again it will hide the countries except for 5. I've been trying to work on this but I have not been successful

One of the things that have crossed my mind are to use `.slice(0, 5)` to display only 5 and have a button under to show the rest but not sure how to get rid of the slice

These are the files and code that I have so far:

**script.js**

```
const bodyElement = document.createElement('template');
bodyElement.innerHTML = `
<div class='list'>
</div>
`
class ShowList extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(bodyElement.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch('countries.json')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let output = '';
        data.forEach(function (item) {
          output += `
          <ul>
            <li>Country: ${item.Country}</li>
            <li>CODE: ${item.ISO2}</li>
          </ul>
        `
        })
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.list').innerHTML = output;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error Fetching data : ${error}`)
        document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = 'Error Loading Data'
      })
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    this.fetchData();
  }
}

customElements.define("show-list", ShowList);
```

**list.html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JSON-JS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>countries: a long list</h1>
    <show-list></show-list>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**A part of my `data.json`**

```
[
    {
        "Country": "Portugal",
        "Slug": "portugal",
        "ISO2": "PT"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Somalia",
        "Slug": "somalia",
        "ISO2": "SO"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Antarctica",
        "Slug": "antarctica",
        "ISO2": "AQ"
    },
    {
        "Country": "China",
        "Slug": "china",
        "ISO2": "CN"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Jamaica",
        "Slug": "jamaica",
        "ISO2": "JM"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Zambia",
        "Slug": "zambia",
        "ISO2": "ZM"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Paraguay",
        "Slug": "paraguay",
        "ISO2": "PY"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
        "Slug": "saint-kitts-and-nevis",
        "ISO2": "KN"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Samoa",
        "Slug": "samoa",
        "ISO2": "WS"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Guinea-Bissau",
        "Slug": "guinea-bissau",
        "ISO2": "GW"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Iceland",
        "Slug": "iceland",
        "ISO2": "IS"
    },
    {
        "Country": "Kyrgyzstan",
        "Slug": "kyrgyzstan",
        "ISO2": "KG"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get rid of the `slice` method. You just have to determine how much of the array you should slice. The choices should either be `5` or `data.length`. The latter will copy the entire array, giving you all items.

For the "show more" toggle, I'd recommend making use of [`attributeChangedCallback` life-cycle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks). With it you can create a toggle like functionality. For example: whenever you component has a `show-all` attribute, it will show all the countries. When it doesn't have the `show-all` attribute, only 5 countries are shown. **NOTE: attributes need to be present in the `observedAttributes` array for the `attributeChangedCallback` to run whenever said attribute has changed.**

Put the rendering logic in a separate function. You'll need to render the countries after the data has been fetched **AND** after the `show-all` attribute has been toggled.

```js
const countryData = [{"Country":"Portugal","Slug":"portugal","ISO2":"PT"},{"Country":"Somalia","Slug":"somalia","ISO2":"SO"},{"Country":"Antarctica","Slug":"antarctica","ISO2":"AQ"},{"Country":"China","Slug":"china","ISO2":"CN"},{"Country":"Jamaica","Slug":"jamaica","ISO2":"JM"},{"Country":"Zambia","Slug":"zambia","ISO2":"ZM"},{"Country":"Paraguay","Slug":"paraguay","ISO2":"PY"},{"Country":"Saint Kitts and Nevis","Slug":"saint-kitts-and-nevis","ISO2":"KN"},{"Country":"Samoa","Slug":"samoa","ISO2":"WS"},{"Country":"Guinea-Bissau","Slug":"guinea-bissau","ISO2":"GW"},{"Country":"Iceland","Slug":"iceland","ISO2":"IS"},{"Country":"Kyrgyzstan","Slug":"kyrgyzstan","ISO2":"KG"}];

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<div class='list'>
</div>

<button>Load more</button>
`;

class ShowCountries extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['show-all'];
  }

  _data = [];

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  /**
   * These getters and setters are shortcuts to getting and setting the attribute.
   * They also allow you to use the attributes as properties, making them easier to use inside of this class.
   */
  get showAll() {
    return this.hasAttribute('show-all');
  }

  set showAll(value) {
    if (value === true) {
      this.setAttribute('show-all', '');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('show-all');
    }
  }

  get list() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.list');
  }

  get button() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
  }

  async _fetchData() {
    try {
      // This is commented out for now because we will simulate a successful request.
      // const res = await fetch('countries.json');
      // this._data = await res.json(); 
      
      this._data = countryData;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error Fetching data : ${error}`)
    }
  }

  /**
   * The amount of countries rendered depends on if the
   * show-all attribute is present or not.
   */
  renderCountries() {
    this.list.innerHTML = '';

    const limit = !this.showAll ? 5 : this._data.length;
    const template = this._data.slice(0, limit).map(item => `
      <ul>
        <li>Country: ${item.Country}</li>
        <li>CODE: ${item.ISO2}</li>
      </ul>`).join('');

    this.list.innerHTML = template;
  }

  /**
   * This runs whenever the show-all attribute has been changed.
   */
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName) {
    if (attrName === 'show-all' && this._data.length) {
      this.renderCountries();
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this._fetchData().then(() => {
      this.renderCountries();
    });

    /**
     * Here we toggle the show-all attribute by clicking the button.
     */
    this.button.addEventListener('click', event => {
      this.showAll = !this.showAll;
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

customElements.define("show-countries", ShowCountries);
```

```html
<h1>countries: a long list</h1>
<show-countries></show-countries>
```